# How to draw a grid of rectangle shaped objects?

Tags: android, object, drawing

I am new to Android and I am still searching for good resources to mine.

My question involves the best way to draw a grid of rectangle shaped objects to the screen. I need each object displayed in the grid to have an initial text (or an int as text) value, and when a user touches that object, the text will change to a colored shape. Also, each object needs to be aware of (or be able to find out) the state of its immediate neighbors.

I don't know which class to extend in order to be able to have both text and shapes display on it, and be able to handle touch input.

Thank you for the help.

Edit:
I apologize, but I don't know how to be more clear. Perhaps some context will help. I have a main activity that takes an int value as input and creates an Intent which sends that value to another activity. That other activity then displays a grid of 100 random numbers. The user needs to select a series of grid spots and a certain number of those spots that the user chose will change from the random number to a colored shape. The spots that change are controlled by logic that I will provide in the code.

Comment: You need to give more context and show what have you tried already, because the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO Q with basic android graph: [Custom dynamic graph in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701175/custom-dynamic-graph-in-android)

#### Android official guide on custom controls

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

#### Android reference page on the View control, which you'll be expanding on

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

#### real world code example of a custom View control (you're particularly interested in `onDraw()` )

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/ringdroid/com/ringdroid/WaveformView.java.htm

Comment: These links appear to be what I was looking for. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a long time after the question has been asked but maybe it will help ppl :)

Add this to "**attrs.xml**" (or create new if needed)

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="RectanglesGridView">
    <attr name="cellSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="cellColor1" format="color" />
    <attr name="cellColor2" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And this is the class - "**RectanglesGridView.java**"

```
package com.gilapps.movinglivewallpaper.UI.views;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;

import com.gilapps.movinglivewallpaper.R;

public class RectanglesGridView extends View {
    private final static float DEFAULT_CELL_SIZE_DP = 10;
    private final static int DEFAULT_CELL_COLOR1 = Color.GRAY;
    private final static int DEFAULT_CELL_COLOR2 = Color.WHITE;
    private int mColor1 = DEFAULT_CELL_COLOR1;
    private int mColor2 = DEFAULT_CELL_COLOR2;
    private float mCellSize;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private boolean mIsColor1;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;

    public RectanglesGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mCellSize = convertDpToPixel(DEFAULT_CELL_SIZE_DP);
        mPaint = new Paint();

    }

    public RectanglesGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        loadAttributes(context, attrs);


    }



    public RectanglesGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        loadAttributes(context, attrs);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public RectanglesGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        loadAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    private void loadAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.RectanglesGridView,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mCellSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RectanglesGridView_cellSize, convertDpToPixel(DEFAULT_CELL_SIZE_DP));
            mColor1 = a.getColor(R.styleable.RectanglesGridView_cellColor1, DEFAULT_CELL_COLOR1);
            mColor2 = a.getColor(R.styleable.RectanglesGridView_cellColor2, DEFAULT_CELL_COLOR2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mCellSize = convertDpToPixel(DEFAULT_CELL_SIZE_DP);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private float convertDpToPixel(float dp){
        Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        return px;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mWidth = w;
        mHeight = h;
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (float r=0;r<mHeight;r+=mCellSize) {
            for (float c=0;c<mWidth;c+=mCellSize) {
                mPaint.setColor(mIsColor1 ? mColor2 : mColor1);
                mIsColor1 = !mIsColor1;
                canvas.drawRect(c,r,c+mCellSize,r+mCellSize,mPaint);
            }
            mIsColor1 = !mIsColor1;
        }


        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<com.gilapps.movinglivewallpaper.UI.views.RectanglesGridView
            app:cellColor1="#33000000"
            app:cellColor2="white"
            app:cellSize="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

- add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the root view
- Change the package name if needed
- Enjoy! :)